Problem with File Picker: Duplicate Image Creation
When using a file picker in my Android application, I'm encountering an issue where selecting images results in duplicates being created on the device. This happens every time I select and potentially upload images using the file picker.
Future<void> _pickFile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      allowMultiple: true,
      type: FileType.image,
      
    );

    if (result != null) {
      setState(() {
        uploadedFiles = result.files;
        uploadedFileNames = result.files.map((file) => file.name).toList();
      });
    }
  }

I'm seeking guidance on how to prevent image duplication when using a file picker in my Android application
